# Please delete [tag:fusion]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I noticed earlier that there was a [fusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fusion) tag. The tag had been used 6 times and was used exclusively to reference VMware Fusion.  I have changed all occurrences of [fusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fusion) to [vmware-fusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-fusion) to make it consistent with the rest of the VMware-* tags.

The [fusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fusion) tag can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a deleted post with that tag, but the tag is now burninated.